# Localizing non-breaking space in Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to localize a Windows 8 Metro style app as described in [a guide on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh965329%28v=win.10%29.aspx). This worked very well so far, but now I'm trying to localize a string containing a non-breaking space which appears in a XAML file (originally as hexadecimal xml-escaped string: &#x00a0).
Just putting the above string into the Resources.resw file does not work, it appears just as &#x00a0.
What do I have to do to get a non-breaking space in my localizations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

&#00a0 is a XML character literal, which means that <foo>&#00a0</foo> has the inner-text equal to the string "\x00a0".

Probably the best thing for you to do is to dynamically reference the string, and perform a replace:

```
var loader = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader();
var str = loader.GetString('Farewell');
var modstring = str.Replace("&#00a0", "\x00a0");
myControl.Text = modstring;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Seems reasonable to me. One thing to watch out: if the resource name contains a dot (like `statusText.Text`), you have to replace the dot with a slash in `GetString()`: `var str = loader.GetString("statusText/Text"); `.